# Set Range to Start at Row 2 in a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

This macro combine all of the columns in an active sheet and appends them to a new column in a worksheet named Mainlist.

The problem that I am facing is that this macro is combining the headers (column names) into the appended column. I need to fix this code so that starts copying at row 2.

I am new to VBA. Please help.

```
Sub ToArrayAndBack()
Dim arr As Variant, lLoop1 As Long, lLoop2 As Long
Dim arr2 As Variant, lIndex As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

ReDim arr2(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count - ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count)

arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value


For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then
            arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
            lIndex = lIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "MasterList" Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not found Then
    Sheets.Add.Name = "MasterList"
End If

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterList")
With ws
     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
     .Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
     .Rows(1).Delete
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your loops at `LBound() + 1`, like this:

```
For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) + 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
  For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) + 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
```

Comment: Woah!  :)  Glad I could help.

Comment: How can I have these pasted values start at A2 in the Masterlist Sheet? I imagine it would have to do with this code `With ws
     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
     .Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
     .Rows(1).Delete
End With`

Comment: Add that text to your original post. It's very hard to read in comments